# DrawImage drawing Incorrect for scaled image

Tags: c#, image

I am capturing desktop screen and drawing on picturebox.

Below is a sample code for testing.Basically i am updating small portion of images on picture box coming from socket. so for performance prospective i am not invalidate whole image always, instead of just invalidate area which need to repaint considering scaling.

On paint event using below DrawImage overload to draw only specific region of picture box

if you try to run below code it not drawing properly.[image: Result Screen]

Text areas are not readable.What is wrong i am doing here.I search extensively but did not got any solution.
Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Bitmap initial = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                               Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                               PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        private Rectangle GetViewRect() { return pictureBox1.ClientRectangle; }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            initial = CaptureDesktop();
            Rectangle imageRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, initial.Width, initial.Height);

            var viewRect = GetViewRect();
            var scaleX = (float)viewRect.Width / initial.Width;
            var scaleY = (float)viewRect.Height / initial.Height;
            // Make sure the target rectangle includes the new block
            var targetRect = Rectangle.FromLTRB(
                (int)Math.Truncate(imageRect.X * scaleX),
                (int)Math.Truncate(imageRect.Y * scaleY),
                (int)Math.Ceiling(imageRect.Right * scaleX),
                (int)Math.Ceiling(imageRect.Bottom * scaleY));
            pictureBox1.Invalidate(targetRect);
            pictureBox1.Update();




        }


        private Bitmap CaptureDesktop()
        {
            var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                               Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                               PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            // Create a graphics object from the bitmap.
            var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

            // Take the screenshot from the upper left corner to the right bottom corner.
            gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                                        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                                        0,
                                        0,
                                        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                                        CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

            return bmpScreenshot;

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            lock (initial)
            {
                e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half;
                e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
                e.Graphics.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;


                var viewRect = GetViewRect();
                var scaleX = (float)initial.Width / viewRect.Width;
                var scaleY = (float)initial.Height / viewRect.Height;
                var targetRect = e.ClipRectangle;
                var imageRect = new RectangleF(targetRect.X * scaleX, targetRect.Y * scaleY, targetRect.Width * scaleX, targetRect.Height * scaleY);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(initial, targetRect, imageRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }

        }
    }
}
`
```

Edit : if i change to below code. it works fine.

```
    e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half;
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
   e.Graphics.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
   e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.High
```

;

Comment: That's just a brain-bug.  If you rescale the image to 10x10 pixel bitmap, do you expect the text to remain readable?  That happens much sooner with an image that contains fine-grained details.  Like text.  You made it a lot worse by using InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor, that completely throws pixels away.   If you want it perfect then you need scrollbars.

Comment: @HansPassant i dont want to use scroll bar. my app is like team viewer. i need to scale image with pictutrebox rectangle

Comment: Such apps don't use screenshots, too slow and too imperfect.  They generally rely on a filter driver that intercepts drawing commands that a program emits, replaying them on the remote monitor.  You can't write drivers with C#, google "c# rdp" to get ahead.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for your comment.my problem is how to draw scale image perfectly without scroll bar using e.Graphics.DrawImage(initial, targetRect, imageRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel); or is there any alternative for that

Comment: Why are you using `e.Graphics.DrawImage`.Use `PictureBox.Image=initial`

Comment: And set the picture box size mode to zoom.

Comment: @preciousbetine as i state above i dont want to refresh picture box each time.most of time there is very small portion need to redraw

Comment: That's the problem with brain-bugs, they are much harder to fix than coding-bugs.  Use InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic, that's as good as it is going to get with this program.